# How to add a gsl library in window using the compiler tcc?

Tags: c, windows, gsl, tcc

At the moment I am able to compile and run a basic "Hello World" programme by using the windows command prompt via the command:

```
tcc.test.c
```

followed by

```
test.exe.
```

where test is the name of the file contaaing the code for the `"Hello World"` programme.

I installed the `tcc` folder ontop of my c:\ drive. I have another programme that requires the `gsl` library to run but I don't know from where and how to correctly install the library and how to call it when the programme compiles and runs.

Comment: Note: there needs to be a space between `tcc` and `test.c`, not a period

Answer (score 0):

you might want to read the documentation at: ;.

which, amongst other things says:

`-Bdir` Set the path where the tcc internal libraries can be found (default is PREFIX/lib/tcc'). "

Also of interest is:

`-Idir' Specify an additional include path. Include paths are searched in the order they are specified. System include paths are always searched after. The default system include paths are: /usr/local/include', /usr/include' and PREFIX/lib/tcc/include'. (PREFIX' is usually /usr' or`/usr/local'). "

and finally:

`-Ldir' Specify an additional static library path for the`-l' option. The default library paths are `/usr/local/lib',`/usr/lib' and `/lib'.

`-lxxx' Link your program with dynamic library libxxx.so or static library libxxx.a. The library is searched in the paths specified by the`-L' option.